# Escaping Quotes using python minidom to create xml file

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing, minidom

I'm using python to create XML files to automate a workflow.

The code I have written is:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
import os

root = minidom.Document()
xml = root.createElement('WASATCH') #main (root) element
xml.setAttribute("ACTION","JOB")

#Create XML File
xml_str = root.toprettyxml(encoding='utf-8',indent="\t") 
xml_file = "EXAMPLE.xml" #name xml file
with open(xml_file, "wb") as f:
    f.write(xml_str)
```

currently the code prints quotes around JOB

```
<WASATCH ACTION="JOB">
```

but I need those removed to just print this

```
 <WASATCH ACTION=JOB>
```

what can I do to remove the quotes around JOB?

Comment: What about your workflow need attributes unquoted? Are you trying to make an XML derivative?

Comment: Also, maybe you understand this already, but it's not _your code_ that prints quotes around `JOB`, it's minidom putting in quotes because that's what XML is/does, and minidom is doing the right thing. Very curious to know why you need to undo that. Welcome, and cheers!

Comment: @ZachYoung I fixed the grammatical mistake. This is to communicate with the printing software. The example files provided all had the attributes unquoted.

Answer (score 1):

Removing quotes will make it invalid xml. If you really want that, take xml_str and replace quotes by your method of choice, e.g.

`new = xml_str.replace(‘“‘,’’)`